# Executor without H2O instance discovered, killing the cloud

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, glm, h2o, sparkling-water

I'm running Tweedie GLM using sparkling water for different sized data ie 20 MB, 400 MB, 2GB,25 GB. Code works fine for **Sampling iteration 10**. But I have to test for large sampling scenario..

```
Sampling iteration is 500
```

In this case code working well for 20 and 400 mb data.But It starts throwing issue when data is larger than 2 GB

After doing search I found one solution disabling change listener but that did not worked for large data.
     **`--conf "spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=1" "spark.ext.h2o.topology.change.listener.enabled=false"`**

Here is my spark submit configuration

```
spark-submit \
     --packages  ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.10:1.6.1, log4j:log4j:1.2.17\
        --driver-memory 8g \
        --executor-memory 10g \
        --num-executors 10\
        --executor-cores 5 \
        --class TweedieGLM  target/SparklingWaterGLM.jar \
        $1\
        $2\
        --conf "spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=1" "spark.ext.h2o.topology.change.listener.enabled=false"
```

This is what I got as an error

```
16/07/08 20:39:55 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on cfclbv0152.us2.oraclecloud.com: Executor heartbeat timed out after 175455 ms
    16/07/08 20:40:00 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on cfclbv0152.us2.oraclecloud.com: remote Rpc client disassociated
    16/07/08 20:40:00 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener anon1 threw an exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executor without H2O instance discovered, killing the cloud!
            at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext$$anon$1.onExecutorAdded(H2OContext.scala:203)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:58)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:56)
            at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:37)
            at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1136)
            at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading carefully the issue posted on github https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/issues/32. I tried couple of options here is what I tried
Added
`--conf "spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=1" "spark.ext.h2o.topology.change.listener.enabled=false" "spark.locality.wait=3000" "spark.ext.h2o.network.mask=10.196.64.0/24"`

```
Changed the :

Executors from 10 to 3,6 9
executor-memory from 4 to 12 and 12 to 24gb
driver-memory from 4 to 12 and 12 to 24gb
```

This is what I learned: GLM is memory intensive job so we have to provide sufficient memory to execute the job.

Answer (score 0):

I will do trouble shoot this problem with using Sparkling water shell and executing one line at a time

- Start shell
- Start H2O
- Monitor the state of cluster

Then

1. Read Input data and cache it
2. Read Yarn logs to find why my tasks are getting killed , many times Yarn preemption kills the executors.
3. Increasing Spark wait time for starting H2O process
4. Decreasing the number of executors to just 3 / increasing cores to 3 / increasing executor memory to 6 GB
5. Monitor Spark UI and H2O Flow UI to see whats going on with memory in each stage

As general rule the memory size of H2O cluster should be 5 times the data input size. With each iteration are you crossing that limit ? 2 GB seems to be very small. We process huge volumes everyday using Sparkling water and Spark.

there are some suggestions on H2o website

https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/doc/configuration/internal_backend_tuning.rst

Comment: For my case I figured out the problem and the solution. Your troubleshoot mechanism also helped to to find out what is going on.